Vinyl siding near from the ground got loose on one end, but locked on the other end and the middle
The video shows how the siding got loose one end.
The middle part and the other end of the siding are completely locked. But, on the right side of the siding is loose. No matter how hard I push or lift the siding, it doesn't lock. and I also tried to push down the siding below it, but it couldn't be moved. It's very low and I couldn't use a siding removal tool. I also saw some ants coming in and out of it, but they're gone. Not sure if it's related to the ants.


Get us a look underneath. It's not easy to diagnose this through an internet tube. My guess is that the siding lip is disengaged from the starter molding, possibly because it was nailed on too low, leaving it loose. Photos are better than video.

@isherwood underneath the siding, it's brick, i don't think there is mold underneath

Technically, the video doesn't show us how the siding got loose, only that it is loose.

@Huesmann As I slide my hand alone the siding, First you hear the sound of the sidings hooking each other, then you don't hear anything. that's where the siding got loose

@Rongeegee that's still where the siding is loose, not how it got that way.

It looks like a "double 4" or "double 5" Dutch lap siding and the bottom of the siding was cut off so it would fit in its place. When the edge is cut, the bottom can lo longer be "hooked" in place with a starter strip. There appears to be a "J" channel below it that it is supposed to fit into. That is how it is typically held in pace when the bottom is cut. There are various sizes of this channel. The picture, is considered a 1/2" J channel.

Picture courtesy Amazon and CertainTeed
That's the dimension between the 2 vertical legs. It comes in 3/4" and smaller too.
To get the siding back into the bottom J channel, you need to start by buckling the  siding to the cut bottom edge raises enough to get into the inside of the j channel.
If there is a portion already in the J channel as it should, a round edged pry bar slipped between the j Channel and siding, should automatically draw the j channel out to allow the siding to slip in where it belongs as the bar is slid it along, keeping the bar vertical. It may be angled a little, but that will let it slip out easily if it is too much of an angle.

The siding extends to the underground. So, you’re saying there is a J channel under the soil that hooks the first siding from the bottom, and one end of the first siding got off the j channel?

From what I see in the video, yes. The better way to confirm is to get a picture from ground level that shows the bottom edge of the siding and whatever it is that is supposed to hold it. My answer is based on what I think  see.

To clarify what I seen. The j channel I peak of is at ground level, not in the ground. A picture from a different angle will help.

look at the picture: https://imgur.com/a/003yZeO. the second siding doesn't hook on the first siding from the bottom

The picture is a big help. There is no J channel there, just more siding that disappears into the ground.... not a good thing at all. It tells me your framing is below grade too. My answer is going in the wrong direction. The ground will need to be dug away to see how far down the siding is. Also how much is below grade. It looks like the siding in the ground has been pushed up which will allow the next piece up do exactly what you see it doing.

the framing is not below grade. Behind that siding, it's the foundation, and I just used a straight piece of wood to measure the straightness of the first siding. It turned out that the first siding was dented. That's probably why the siding wasn't hooked. I will show you on a video or picture tomorrow.
